# Can Jesus' death be considered as a suicide?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, death, will-of-god

As God is Omnipotent and Omnipresent, he already knew that is going to die and since he is all powerful he could have escaped the death. As he willingly did it, can it be considered as a suicide?

As it the same as some one drinking poision, knowing that drinking it would kill him?

And can it be told that 'God' send his only begotten son on a suicide mission?

Comment: Before the point of death - as crucifixion, naturally speaking, would have resulted - Jesus expired, voluntarily. John 10:18. 'No man taketh it from me'. But it was _men that put him in that position_ .

Answer (score 5):

All legal courts seem to recognise the difference between, say, a soldier voluntarily proceeding on a mission that is virtually guaranteed to end in his death, and in an individual deciding to throw themselves off a high bridge to end their own life.

"Rear-guard action" is a military tactic to use a few soldiers to protect the lives of many by holding back the enemy, so that the many get time to escape death. The chances of surviving rear-guard action are extremely slight, so those engaging in it are showing willingness to risk sacrificing their lives for the sake of saving many others. It is the opposite with most suicides; life is being given up on. When a suicidal person attempts to end their own life but in the process also ends the lives of innocent others, albeit unintentionally, then the suicidal person commits crimes against humanity.

With Jesus, it was utterly the opposite to that.  Crimes had been committed against God, yet God, in Christ, became man so that his sinless death could provide a totally just, legal basis for Deity to punish sin (i.e. to punish Christ) so that all those accepting that free provision could be pardoned and not have to "go down" themselves.

Given that God's law is that death can only claim sinners (Romans 6:23), Christ could not be held by Death, but Death had to let go of him, and so he arose from the grave (Acts 2:23-28). This was proof that he had given himself over to death without having sinned, and that he was, indeed, who he claimed to be - the Son of God (Romans 1:1-4).

Jesus allowed wicked men to put him to death unjustly (Acts 2:23), knowing that  God would punish him for the sins that we ought to be punished for. When punishment for a crime has been administered, there cannot be a second trial or a second punishment. God poured all his wrath against sin against his sinless Son. (Acts 3:13-1) Therefore, when people repentantly put their trust in that provision, they come 'under' that covering protection.

Thus, all three of your questions require the biblical answer, "No."